# How many items can a level 14 College of Creation Bard make with a singular usage of Performance of Creation?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard

I originally thought this had a clear cut answer based on the first two sentences of Creative Crescendo, with 'at once' referring to the moment of using Performance of Creation.

> When you use your Performance of Creation feature, you can **create more than one item at once**. The number of items equals your Charisma modifier (minimum of two items).

But the ability to create multiple items at once doesn't do anything if it doesn't also lift the cap of (1) on the number of items that can be maintained from (which was established in Performance of Creation)

> You can have only one item created by this feature at a time; if you use this action and already have an item from this feature, the first one immediately vanishes.

So the Creative Crescendo feature must be removing that cap (setting it to CHA mod, minimum 2); otherwise if a bard Performance'd of Creation more than one item with one usage of the feature, the items (past the first) would just instantly vanish for breaking the limit.

So I am not sure if the language of

> you can create more than one item at once

Should be read as

"at once" = 'in a single usage of Performance of Creation'

or

"at once" = 'in multiple uses of Performance of Creation, but simultaneously existing with other creations'

tl;dr Which of these interpretations is correct:

1. Performance of Creation, even with Creative Crescendo, makes one item per use; the text in Creative Crescendo only lifts the restriction on the maximum number of items the bard can maintain to their CHA mod (minimum two).
2. Performance of Creation with Creative Crescendo lets you make CHA mod (minimum two) items per usage. Creative Crescendo also lifts the restriction on the maximum number of items the bard can maintain to their CHA mod (minimum two).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You might want to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Your second interpretation is correct, Creative Crescendo allows you to make up to your Charisma modifier of items at a time.

From the description of Creative Crescendo:

> When you use your Performance of Creation feature, you can create more than one item at once. The number of items equals your Charisma modifier (minimum of two items). If you create an item that would exceed that number, you choose which of the previously created items disappears.

The phrase "you can create more than one item at once" is modifying "when you use your Performance of Creation" feature, and means, as you suggest, "in a single usage of Performance of Creation".

What you can do is "create more than one at item at once" and you can do it "when you use your Performance of Creation".  In particular, you can create more than one item "at once".

And yes, it is changing the rules of Performance of Creation.  At 3rd level, you can create "one nonmagical item", at 14th, now can create more than one item at a time.

If the language said, "When you use your Performance of Creature feature, more than one item can exist at once", then that would mean that still only one object can be created at a time.